# How can I change the color or bounds of a Java Component without subclassing it?

Tags: java, animation, awt, javaquery

I am working with the Java [timing framework](https://java.net/projects/timingframework) to perform animations. What I would like is to be able to perform some animation on an `AWT` or `Swing` *Component* without subclassing it. Animations I am interested in include changing the bounds, color, or alpha. There are numerous examples online of how to subclass a `Component`, then override the `paint(Graphics)` method in order to perform such changes, however I would like to find a different approach.

I have tried obtaining the graphics for a `Component` by calling

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) component.getGraphics();
```

Then manipulating it - such as setting the alpha value:

```
AlphaComposite newComposite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, newVal);
g2d.setComposite(newComposite);
component.repaint();
```

However this did nothing. I have tried other approaches - such as using custom `TimingTarget`s, or `PropertySetter`s, but I have not had any luck. What is the correct approach?

To give more context to this question, this is for my [javaQuery](http://bit.ly/javaquery) library, which is a port of *jQuery* to *Java*, and is modeled after my previous project (with working animations) [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery).

Comment: `What is the correct approach`. Subclassing

Comment: For bounds and colour, doesn't component have methods for those?

Comment: @Cruncher, they do - but I have not seen these work correctly in an animation. There is a `setBackground` method which accepts a `Color`, and a `setBounds` method that accepts a `Rectangle` - however I have not been able to see these update.

Comment: This probably depends on the layout manager. When java uses everything through a layout manager, things like setBounds will probably only work if you use setLayout(null);

Comment: can you tell us why you don't want to subclass?

Comment: `There are numerous examples online of how to subclass a Component, then override the paint(Graphics) method`- the proper way to customize is to override `paintComponent()` not paint(). You should not be using getGraphics(). `however I have not been able to see these update.` - then your code is wrong. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problems. Animations are done by using a `Swing Timer`.

Comment: @camickr, Unfortunately there is no SSCCE to post - There are hundreds of lines of code to help support this reflection-based animation feature, as well as a custom `AnimatorSet` class that allow the animation of multiple objects on one `Swing Timer`. What I am looking for is a basic explanation to get me in the right direction.

Comment: @mrhobo, I cannot subclass because I am making an advanced convenience library for which I want developers to be able to use without modifying their existing `Component` classes.

Comment: How about using an aspect?

Answer (score 0):

Use swing (or JFX). AWT is old and less customizable as it uses native platform components: peers every Java AWT component with a native one.

With bounds I assume border
You can set borders (even additive) and colors. `setOpaque(false)` allows transparency.

Getting the component's Graphics should never be done. A component receives a paint event, in a well defined context: single threaded on the event handling thread, clipped, positioned and more.

So use the component's setters, `invalidate` should that be needed`. And possibly a` repaint(50L)`.